# Which waves are produced during tuning fork vibration?

Tags: waves, acoustics, vibrations

In my book, it is written that transverse waves are produced during physical motion of tuning fork.   But vibration of tuning fork produces sound which are compressional in nature . 
Please tell me the correct answer and reason behind it.

Comment: "in this case." Which case, the waves in the air or the physical motion of the the tuning fork itself? There are probably both compression/longitudinal and transverse waves in the tuning fork, and depending on how you strike the fork, torsional waves.

Answer (score 2):

The acoustic wave in air is a longitudinal wave. The mechanical movement of arms of the tuning fork could be interpreted as a transversal wave, but it's actually more of vibration. There is no real wave propagation.

Comment: *There is no real wave propagation.* Huh? How do you think a tuning fork emits sound then?

Comment: @Hilmar (but also to Bill N). *There is no real wave propagation.*
Vibration of an extended body *always* involves wave propagation.
Vibration modes are nothing but stationary waves. And a tuning fork is
a good frequency standard because it's relatively insensitive to the
exact excitation way. Probably because there is a mode much less
damped than the others and after a short time it survives alone.

Comment: As to OP question, the standard mode of vibration of a tuning fork is
transverse: displacement orthogonal wrt prongs' length. That vibration
mode, together with prongs' shape, is well suited to excite a
compression wave in air.

Comment: @ElioFabri Actually the transverse vibration of the prongs is very *badly* suited to excite air vibrations, because the sound radiated from the equal opposite motion of the prongs cancels out almost exactly. If you hold a tuning fork close to your ear and rotate it, you will discover that the sound is highly directional. A tuning fork generates sound efficiently because the *base* of the fork vibrates *axially*, and when you press it against a large flexible surface (e.g. a table top) the complete table top vibrates and creates the sound in the air.

Comment: @Gert it is true that *theoretically* you can analyse the motion of any vibrating system as superimposed travelling waves, but in practice *nobody* does that except for very simple situations like waves in a string. For more complicated objects (like a tuning fork) you just find the normal modes of vibration and work with those.

Comment: @alephzero You're right. After writing my comment I recalled just the
experiment you are quoting of a tuning fork whose handle is pressed
against a table. I also add that in science museums tuning forks can
be seen mounted over a wooden box with an open side. It makes clear
that sound radiation doesn't come directly from fork but from the air
in the box, put into vibration by the box' wall touching the fork's
base.

Answer (score 1):

A tuning fork vibrates like this (in its fundamental mode):

[image: Tuning fork]

([image from here](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/TuningFork/fork-modes.html))

As the tines move sideways they alternately compress and expand the air next to them:

[image: Tuning fork]

So the sideways motion of the times produces a compression wave in the air.

Comment: Add to that that the base is also moving ("up" and "down" in those drawings). Putting it on a sounding board makes it much loader. Or on a resonance box with a length of about one quarter of the wavelength in air.